# HTML5 Offline issue in Opera

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

Im having problem with HTML5 offline in Opera browser.

If the Opera turbo is ON, then getting the window.applicationcache.status as always 0. So the offline download is not happening. If the turbo is OFF, then the offline download works without any issue.

Can anyone help me on this.